# Differences between running OSX App from Finder versus Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, finder

Differences between running OSX App from Finder versus Xcode ???

System is iMac 27” all-in-1 running Mavericks OSX 10.9.5  and latest Xcode 6.0.1

The App reads a binary file and writes two text files, may re-write the binary file, and draws in a
window client area.

App totally runs in Xcode. App, binary file and two text files are in ~/Debug or ~/Release directory.
No problem writing to files. File i/o code does this…

```
std::fstream out(  binary_file, std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
if ( out )
out.read(buffer, MaxBuffer);
out.close();

ofstream info(“info_file.txt”);
if ( info.is_open() )
info << text;
info.close();
system("chmod 777 info_file.txt"); //tried this, doesn’t help

ofstream clout(“clout_file.txt”);
if ( clout.is_open() )
clout << text;
clout.close();
system("chmod 777 clout_file.txt"); //tried this, doesn’t help
```

App cannot write to files when run (double clicked) from Finder. Regardless of where App and files are located…

/Users/myname/Applications/Appname

/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Appname

Other

I should say the App is Archive/Release built in Xcode and placed in destination directory for
Finder situation. Is this the right way? This is my first OSX App but I’ve been programming for
decades.

Permissions for Finder situation are

App: myname Read & Write, staff Read only, everyone Read only
binary file:  myname Read & Write, staff Read & Write, everyone Read & Write
text files: myname Read & Write, staff Read & Write, everyone Read & Write

I’ve checked all the permissions in directory tree in Unix terminal also.
/Users/myname/…

Xcode versus Finder, what are the differences? regarding…

user name (byname)

group name (staff, root, admin)

working directory on startup

permissions on App and files (read, write, execute)

location of App and files

would /tmp location for file writing work?

where would be the best place to put App and files?

App working directory is changed by App to be where App and files are located.
Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options -> Working Directory set to same location.
This doesn’t help the Finder run situation.

A MS Windows version of this App works fine.
I have ported it, re-written it, for iMac OSX environment and it runs great in Xcode.
What is wrong with Finder case? Why can’t files be opened in output mode?

I’m thinking of re-writing the file i/o in objective-c style but it would be a pain and should not be
necessary. CString versus NSString is a big pain for me. I have had to use .mm and
objective- c++ source type to get this far.

Ideas welcome and thanks.

Comment: You should just set the working directory to somewhere sensible at startup, rather than relying on whatever the working directory happens to be upon launch (typically it's `/` when launched from the Finder). Either that or use full paths for your files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App won't write to file when run from Finder (ok in Xcode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149445/app-wont-write-to-file-when-run-from-finder-ok-in-xcode)

Comment: App working directory is changed by App to be where App and files are located.

Comment: You mean you call `chdir` or similar at startup ? Oh no - I see you're talking about the scheme in Xcode - this only applies when running from Xcode - it doesn't affect what happens when you run from the command line or from the Finder.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Where is somewhere sensible? Maybe I'll try full paths.

Comment: You could just use the home directory, or the Documents directory, which is inside the home directory. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020187/getting-home-directory-in-mac-os-x-using-c-language

Comment: To change directory I do this..        
        
        if ([filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath: wherever] == NO)
            NSLog (@"Cannot change directory.");
        
        currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
        
        NSLog (@"Current directory is %@", currentpath);

Comment: Thanks Paul again.

I tried full path names AND home directory (/Users/me/Documents) and IT WORKS!!!

I think it’s full path names. I will verify.

Terrific!

Comment: Awesome - well done!

Comment: Full path names solve all issues. Tried multiple directories. Okay. Awesome to you.

Answer (score 1):

Full path names resolves all issues with running from Finder. Multiple directory locations were tried successfully. Awesome thanks to Paul R.

Comment: By this you mean e.g. `ofstream clout(“~/out/clout_file.txt”);`?